# Combine JS Files Through Servlet Mapping

Tags: java, tomcat, web, tomcat7

I have a js library that I am trying to implement, https://github.com/rpatil26/webutilities.

It is asking for all scripts to be comma separated in the src attribute.  It will then take these and merge them into 1 script and return it.  This is the servlet mapping that I have setup

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSCSSMergeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is an example of my src:

```
/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min,/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/head.core.1.0.3.min,/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/jweb/jquery.jweb,/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/datatables/1.10.7/jquery.dataTables,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/datatables.colsearch.plugin,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/bootstrap.min,/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/jquery.formatter.min,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/bootstrap-dialog,/WebExchangeStruts/struts/js/datatables/1.10.7/dataTables.responsive,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/jqResponsiveTable,/WebExchangeStruts/js/common/header,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/pace.min,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/jBox.min,/WebExchangeStruts/js/lib/bootstrap-dialog-listener.js
```

My servlet pattern does not match when this is there.  I can reduce it to 1 script and the pattern matches and the servlet picks it up ok.  Is there anything I can do to match this pattern and get the servlet to fire?

**Actual Question:** The big long string of comma separated js files is being put into the src of a single script tag.  The servlet is not matching on the url-pattern for this string so the library is never getting called.  Is there a way to revise my url-pattern that would cause a match on this string?

**Update** 
having additional "." in the file name is causing the pattern to not match.  Still looking for a solution for a url-pattern that will work with this situation.

Comment: no, that was intentional per the docs in webutilities.  It said to only put it on the last one.  However, I had a thought that maybe the .min was causing the url-pattern to not match somehow?

Comment: np, thanks for checking it out

Comment: The extension is easy to get the content of different kind should be added to the url if the resource already has it.  Mapping is just a way to match this resource. If you map it by extension, then only resources with extension will be served by this servlet.

Comment: @RomanC I am not understanding what you are saying I should be matching on?  I did confirm that it is the .min or .whatever that is causing the pattern to not match

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.